# Read 5 lines from a panda dataframe and insert it in one cell per line in another panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I am reading data from an excel file:
the dataframe resulting is an array with a single column and several lines:

```
   identifier
0        6051
1         771
2        6051
3        5219
4        3667
      ...
6023      771
6024     6051
6025      772

[6026 rows x 1 columns]
```

What I need is to create a new dataframe with 1205 lines (6025/5) and one single column where I insert in each line single cell 5 values from original dataframe:
The result should be something like this

```
   identifier
0        6051 771  6051 5219 3667
1        2578 3697 24   7865 7852
2        635  6987 2485 3658 2587
3        219  8579 2569 1478 3698
4        567  5974 6587 8752 6848
      ...
1203      981 6987 2547 369  4752
1204     5651 6987 3975 6975 3974
1205      662 6975 2354 1284 1298

[1205 rows x 1 columns]
```

I am reading original dataframe just like this:

```
file = '01-03-2010.xlsx'
require_cols = [0]


df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Folha2', usecols = require_cols)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sentence'])
```

df2 is the resulting dataframe.

Can anyone help? 
BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
df['group'] = df.index//5 # add extra column to hold the group value
new_df = df.groupby('group').identifier.apply(list).apply(pd.Series)
df.drop('group', axis=1) # drop the extra column that was created.
print(new_df.head())
```

Edit:

**Input**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=6026), columns=["identifier"])
df.head()

identifier
0   752
1   14
2   184
3   139
4   37
```

**Solution**

```
df['group'] = df.index//5
df1 = df.groupby('group').identifier.apply(list).apply(pd.Series).fillna(0)
df1 = df1.astype('int32')
df1.head()

    0   1   2   3   4
group                   
0   752 14  184 139 37
1   716 499 902 54  565
2   74  427 939 380 244
3   651 803 97  78  492
4   169 376 737 342 616
```

**Solution 2:** (one column with array of 5 elements)

```
df['group'] = df.index//5
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('group').identifier.apply(list))
df1.head()

    identifier
group   
0   [752, 14, 184, 139, 37]
1   [716, 499, 902, 54, 565]
2   [74, 427, 939, 380, 244]
3   [651, 803, 97, 78, 492]
4   [169, 376, 737, 342, 616]
```

Comment: the result of your code creates 5 columns per line, what I really need are 5 values in a single column per line [value1 value2 value3 value4 value5] next line [value6 value7 value8 value9 value10] and so one

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to group 5 elements in a single cell? the result would be an array with 1205 lines per one column and each cell with 5 values

Comment: data type can be a string